# Docker URI documentation

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I noticed a new URI format for docker run. It is used in the "Try on Desktop" button here:

https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/

The link there has the following format:

```
<a href="docker://repository/run/redis">...</a>
```

Does anyone know the format for this URI< and where there is documentation for it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any documentation for this URI, but it's meant for kitematic (https://kitematic.com/)
You can find information on that announcement on docker's blog:
https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/introducing-button-on-docker-hub-to-create-containers-locally/